# SSRS 2008 TimeDataRetrieval timings

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting-services

I've a report with an odd performance issue. When running it under the following conditions, SSRS Server (`UAT_SSRS`) & SQL Server (`SERVER_SQL`) I'm getting a `TimeDataRetrieval` value of 23726. When I run it under a different SSRS server (`PROD_SSRS`) and still use the same SQL server, the `TimeDataRetrieval` value is 325952 (well over **ten times more**) for the exact same parameters.

My understanding is that the `TimeDataRetrieval` covers both the connection handling & data set retrieval of the data. Why would there be such a huge difference between these two reports?

Answer (score 0):

The value comes from the ReportServer database associated with the SSRS installation. It's nothing to do the SQL Server instance that hosts the RS DBs.

So, this simply says that your prod SSRS is around 14 times busier than your UAT SSRS. And they have different backend metadata databases, even if they are on the same SQL Server instance.

Comment: thanks gbn, I understand that this value refers to the Report server database but I'm a little confused. My understanding is that the TimeDataRetrieval value is a metric that measures the time taken in opening the connection to the data source & also retrival of data from the data source, so in that respect is it not measuring the performance of the data source. And if so why would there be such a dramatic difference between the 2 values ? Could it be that the configuration of the connection is different, I don't have access to the back-end of these servers unfortunately.